# I have a new Rails 3 app on ruby 1.8.7, what's the impact of moving to 1.9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm newish to rails, and I started with rails 3 and ruby 1.8.7

I'm not sure exactly why I went with 1.8.7, but I think it was because many gems are not supported with 1.9.

Was my analysis wrong and I can move to 1.9?
What are things to consider moving to 1.9?  Is rails 3 ready for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've moved to 1.9.2 about two months ago and so far everything seems OK. 1.9 is largely backwards-compatible so most things are not a problem.

That said there are two possible sources of significant annoyance when going to 1.9:

- CSV parsing. Ruby switched internally to FasterCSV but doing `require 'fastercsv'` will result in an error. This will require changes to your code if you are doing any CSV parsing.
- Encoding changes. If your code (not data) includes non-ascii characters your app will fall apart. The fix is not hard, you have to put the magic comment `# encoding: utf-8` on top of any such files, but again a possible source of pain.

All gems I've been using work fine (except those doing CSV).

Comment: +1 — Definitely watch out for any potential character encoding gotchas. If you switch to the newer mysql2 gem (if you're using MySQL) you'll notice it too uses UTF-8 by convention.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to find out for your application is to use rvm and install 1.9.2.  Upgrade all of your gems using Bundler and then run all of your tests.  Manual testing of the application will ferret out any remaining issues that are not common and specific to your code and data.